# How to find decimal representation of years in R?

Tags: r, date, time, lubridate

Since I need reasonably accurate representations of years in decimal format (~ **4-5 digits** of accuracy would work) I turned to the lubridate package. This is what I have tried:

```
refDate <- as.Date("2016-01-10")
endDate <- as.Date("2020-12-31")
daysInLeapYear <- 366
daysInRegYear <- 365
leapYearFractStart <- 0
leapYearRegStart <- 0
daysInterval <- as.interval(difftime(endDate, refDate, unit = "d"), start = refDate)
periodObject <- as.period(daysInterval)
if(leap_year(refDate)) {
    leapYearFractStart <- (as.numeric(days_in_month(refDate))-as.numeric(format(refDate, "%d")))/daysInLeapYear
}
if(!leap_year(refDate)) {
    leapYearRegStart <- (as.numeric(days_in_month(refDate))-as.numeric(format(refDate, "%d")))/daysInRegYear
}
returnData <- periodObject@year+(periodObject@month/12)+leapYearFractStart+leapYearRegStart
```

It is safe to assume that the end date is always at the end of a month, hence no leap year check at the end. Relying on lubridate for proper year/month counting I am adjusting for leap-years only for the start date.

I recon this gets me to within **3 digits of accuracy only**! In addition, it looks a bit crude.

Is there a more complete and accurate procedure to determine decimal representation of years in an interval?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very unclear what you're trying to do exactly here, which makes accuracy difficult to talk about.

`lubridate` has a function `decimal_date` which turns dates into decimals. But since 3 decimal places gives you 1000 possible positions within a year, when we only have 365/366 days, there are between 2 and 3 viable values that fall within a day. Accuracy depends on when in the day you want the result to fall.

```
> decimal_date(as.POSIXlt("2016-01-10 00:00:01"))
[1] 2016.025
> decimal_date(as.POSIXlt("2016-01-10 12:00:00"))
[1] 2016.026
> decimal_date(as.POSIXlt("2016-01-10 23:59:59"))
[1] 2016.027
```

In other words, going beyond 3 decimal places is only really important if you're interested in the time of day.

Comment: Thanks decimal_date() is exactly what I need, didn't know it was there. Great answer, thank you! I am in fact interested in the time of day.

Answer (score 4):

This solution uses only base R.   We get the beginning of the year using `cut(..., "year")` and the number of days in the year by differencing it with the beginning of the next year obtained using `cut(..., "year")` on an arbitrary date in the following year.  Finally use those quantities to get the fraction and add it to the year.

```
d <- as.Date(c("2015-01-31", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-10", "2016-12-31")) # sample input

year_begin <- as.Date(cut(d, "year"))
days_in_year <- as.numeric( as.Date(cut(year_begin + 366, "year")) - year_begin )
as.numeric(format(d, "%Y")) + as.numeric(d - year_begin) / days_in_year
## [1] 2015.082 2016.000 2016.025 2016.997
```

Alternately, using `as.POSIXlt` this variation crams it into one line:

```
with(unclass(as.POSIXlt(d)),1900+year+yday/as.numeric(as.Date(cut(d-yday+366,"y"))-d+yday))
## [1] 2015.082 2016.000 2016.025 2016.997
```